# How to assign a widget to placeholder in FadeInImage?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Code:**

```
FadeInImage(
  placeholder: MyOwnWidget(), // error
  image: NetworkImage(url),
)
```

I want to provide my own widget to `placeholder`, how can I do that, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like it isn't possible with `FadeInImage` and I'll have to use

```
Image.network(
  url,
  loadingBuilder: (_, child, progress) {
    if (progress == null) return child;
    return MyOwnWidget();
  },
)
```

Comment: but this does not "fade"

Answer (score 5):

Just pass the empty string ('') to `placeholder`, which triggers the `placeholderErrorBuilder` callback. And provide your placeholder widget.

You can check the below example.

```
return ClipOval(
  child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
    placeholder: '',
    image: url,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    fadeInDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    fadeOutDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
    placeholderErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) => placeholder,
    imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) => placeholder,
  ),
);
```

And the `placeholder` widget for reference.

```
Widget placeholder = CircleAvatar(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xffE6E6E6),
  radius: 30,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.person,
    color: Color(0xffCCCCCC),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```
Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            Center(
              child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                image: 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

For transparent image use
https://pub.dev/packages/transparent_image